# How can I shorten this graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph like this

[image]

My codes are like this

```
ggplot(data=m_data, aes(x=factor(madde.sayisi), y= guvenirlik, colour=guvenirlik.kestirimi)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(guvenirlik.kestirimi)),size=3) + 
  facet_grid(yontem+orneklem.buyuklugu~formul) + 
  ylim(0.850,1) + 
  scale_shape_discrete(name="guvenirlik.kestirimi") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color="black"))
```

My graph is too long. I want it to look like this.
[image]

Please help me, thank you...

Comment: What do you mean "nest the right y-axis"?  And how would you like it to look?  You can use `size`, `shape`, `alpha` and `color` as aesthetics inside your plot.  Maybe including `shape=orneklem.buyuklugu` in your aes will help?  Without more information about your data and what you're looking for its hard to give a good answer.

Comment: I edited my question, and add a screen shot about how I want it to look like

Comment: Not clear why your graph would be shorter that way, but try facet_grid(orneklem.buyuklugu+yontem~formul)

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: Do you also want the vertical facets to be of different widths? (That is, neither all the same width nor the x-axes having the same spacing?)